# Difference between calling contract.function(), contract.function.call() and contract.function.sendTransaction({})

Tags: solidity, contract-development

What is the difference between calling:

- `contract.function()`
- `contract.function.call()`
- `contract.function.sendTransaction({from:myaddress})`

I know that `contract.function.call()` means a local dry run, whereas chaining `sendTransaction` means that it is run normally and there are side-effects on the blockchain. What about `contract.function()`?